# Recover old website off waybackmachine

Tags: archive, data-recovery

Is there a way to recover an entire website from the waybackmachine?

I have an old site that is archived but no longer have the website files to revive it again. Is there a way to recover the old data so I can get my long lost files back?

Comment: What do you mean by 'website files' - just the html? If yes, then surely you could just go to that webpage and download the source from there through your browser.

Comment: Yes, html, css, images, & possibly php files. This has multiple pages with images and custom css.

Comment: I've came accross the same issue and I've ended up coding a gem. To install: `gem install wayback_machine_downloader` then run it with the base url of the website you want to retrieve as a parameter: `wayback_machine_downloader http://example.com` More information: https://github.com/hartator/wayback_machine_downloader

Answer (score 47):

[wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) is a great tool to mirror an entire site and if you are on windows, you can use [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) to install it. The following command will mirror a site: *wget -m domain.name*

#### Update from comments:

The example wget command that the wont ascend to the parent dir (`-np`), ignores robot.txt (`-e robots=off`), uses the cdn domain (`--domains=domain.name`), and mirrors a url (the url to mirror, `http://an.example.com` ). All together you get:

```
 wget -np -e robots=off --mirror --domains=staticweb.archive.org,web.archive.org http://web.archive.org/web/19970708161549/http://www.google.com/
```

If you are dealing with `https` and a self signed cert, u can use `--no-check-certificate` to disable the certificate check. The wget help is the best place to see possible options.

Comment: Thank you for the resource, much appreciated. I have a mac and app called site sucker which seems to do the same thing. The problem is downloading through a full archive.org url.

Comment: + 1 for help with **blocked recursive crawling**! This should be approved answer.

Comment: `-np` helps to don't get off from the specified date path.

Comment: Great, thanks. And for a great guide to install `wget` on Mac OSX without homebrew or similar, checkout http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/install-and-configure-wget-on-os-x/

Comment: When using https add --no-check-certificate

Comment: Good stuff, I will update the example.

Comment: @mguymon But is there any way to download the css and photos with that command?

Comment: @jcarlosweb you'll need to remove `-np`, and then it's a good idea to limit recursion, for example `-l 3`

Comment: Replying to @jcarlosweb — no, you need a few more options, e.g.: `wget 
     --recursive 
     --no-clobber 
     --page-requisites 
     --html-extension 
     --convert-links 
     --restrict-file-names=windows 
     --domains domain.tld 
              my.domain.tld/`, take a look at https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/downloading-entire-web-site-wget (note: this will work for web.archive.org as well, just add the extra options)